# fixing color saturation using histogram normalization

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am developing a filter to work on images. After applying this filter to images, I am getting some RGB values which are more than 255 or less than 0. I can saturate this pixels to 255 and 0 respectively, but then the image is not good.

I want to find a way to normalize the pixel histograms so after normalization the values for RGB be between 0,255.

The code is as follow:

```
  double max = outputPixel.Cast<double>().Max();
  double targetMax = 300;
  double min = outputPixel.Cast<double>().Min();
  double targetMin = -50;
  for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
  {
       for (int i = 0; i < outputPixel.GetLength(0); i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < outputPixel.GetLength(1); j++)
           {
                outputPixel[i, j, c] = wb[c] * (((outputPixel[i, j, c] - min) * (targetMax-targetMin) / (max - min))+targetMin);
                    outputPixel[i, j, c] = Saturate(outputPixel[i, j, c]);
                }
            }

        }
     }
```

The outputPixel defined as

```
  private static double[, ,] outputPixel;
```

and initialized as follow:

```
    outputPixel = new double[inputImage.Width, inputImage.Height, 3];
```

The problem is:

If I don't do histogram normalization, then there is a lot of specke type noise on dark areas and most of the image is bleached out.

If I use histogram normalization, then I can see a red tint on white area (mainly cloud area).

One solution is to normalize histogram in HSB, but I can not use internal C# calculation for HSB as values for RGB are bigger (or smalle) than 255 (0).

What Can I do in C#?

Comment: Are you scaling all the component values proportionally? If you get red tint you might scale each component individually without keeping the relation between the other two components...

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Yes  I am trying to keep the rate unchanged between colours by finding the max of RGB (finding max of R and G and B and then max of all of them) and also min and using them for conversion. I also tested the came that the rate of change for R and G and B calculated separately, but the result is the same.